# Visual studio , Build tools needed to be installed or not

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am wondering for a long time As I am working with visual studio 2019 and I have all of the tools in my Visual studio 2019 installation , so do I need to update build tools which comes separately in vs installer, do we even need these build tools installation ,for our work environment , I don't think  I have even used these, ( may sound a dumb question but I am curious)

Comment: Are you getting any error while installing any packages?....if so then you can use this link to download Build tools for VC 2019. Link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: If you have Visual Studio 2019 installed, you don't need to install "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019". The description for "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019" states: "These Build Tools allow you to build native and managed MSBuild-based applications without requiring the Visual Studio IDE."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need them.
However, I install them as well because it enables me to develop and test the build scripts on my machine which will run then on build servers which have the Visual Studio Build Tools installed only.

Comment: ok! so it means if I don't update them , then it will not affect my  other projects in any way.

Comment: as long as you're not explicitly using the VS Build Tools environment, it shouldn't.